# Can the Intermediate Value Theorem be proved by Heine-Borel Lemma?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Can the Intermediate Value Theorem be proved by Heine-Borel Lemma, and how?
I mean "Every open cover of close interval has a finite subcover", without compactness etc.

Because in class we proved it via Cantor's Lemma... But Cantor's Lemma gives me a certain point in the function domain that I can work with, but how do I find this point with Hiene-Borel?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you are thinking of H**ei**ne-Borel?

Answer (score 7):

In [reverse mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics), the intermediate value theorem is true in a weaker axiom system, $RCA_0$, than Heine-Borel, which requires $WKL_0$.

This means that there are models of weak second-order theories of numbers in which IVT is true but Heine-Borel is not.

That doesn't mean you can't prove it from Heine-Borel, just that the IVT is more"basic."

(Indeed, $WKL_0$ is equivalent to $RCA_0$ with Heine-Borel added, and it is known to be strictly stronger axiom system - the Weak König's Lemma is provably independent from $RCA_0$.)

Comment: But I can use the lemma to prove Heine–Cantor theorem (on $R$)?
What about Extreme value theorem? I proved that if f is continuous in the closed and bounded interval [a,b], then f is bounded, using the lemma. but what about the part that f must attain minimum and maximum? Can I prove this using the lemma (I know I can use the fact that it bounded, after I prove it)?

Comment: If you are using IVT to prove H-B, you are also using some stronger theorem.

Comment: What about what I asked?

Comment: If you want to know why I never answered here, just re-read your last comment as if you were me, a person who was trying to help you for free. Is it possible I misread your question? Yes. Is it possible you wrote something ambiguous or you didn't understand me? Possibly. But your comment made me uninterested in figuring any of that out. @user3697301

Answer (score 3):

My first thought is no, because the Intermediate Value theorem and Heine-Borel theorem leverage different properties of the unit interval, connectedness and compactness, respectively. But let's see if we can turn the IVT into something using compactness:

Let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ be a continuous function, and let $f(a)<c<f(b)$. Define $g(x)=|f(x)-c|$; then $g$ is also continuous, and by the extreme value theorem (which can be proven using Heine-Borel) $g$ takes a minimum at some $y$. If $g(y)=0$ we are done, otherwise $g(y)=r>0$ and the range of $f$ misses the interval $(c-r,c+r)$.

Well, we managed to widen the "hole" in the range of $f$ from a point to an interval, but we still haven't gotten any closer to the contradiction. Of course we could consider the smallest $x$ such that $f(x)\ge c$, but then we would be back to the standard proof. Interestingly, the point $y$ *is* actually a root; it just doesn't have all the properties that we need to finish the proof (being a *minimal* root does the trick).

Answer (score 1):

Heine-Borel is equivalent to compactness for $\Bbb R^n$ spaces. Here is a proof using compactness.

**Theorem.** *Let $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function. If $f(a)f(b) \lt 0$, then there exists a point $c$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=0$.*

*Proof.* Without loss of generality, assume $f(a)\lt 0\lt f(b)$. Suppose that for each point $x\in[a,b]$, we have $f(x)\neq 0$. By continuity, for each $x\in[a,b]$ there's a $\delta_x\gt 0$ such that $f$ does not change sign in $I_x = (x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x)$. We can take $\delta_x$ so small that at least one of the endpoints of $I_x$ lies within $[a,b]$.

Notice that if $f(x)\gt 0$ and $f(y)\lt 0$ then $I_x\cap I_y = \emptyset$

So the collection $\{I_x\}_{x\in[a,b]}$ is an open cover for $[a,b]$ which is compact, so there's a finite subcollection say $\{I_j\}_{j=1}^n$ that covers $[a,b]$. Let's name them from left to right, namely
\begin{gather*}
I_j = (a_j,b_j) \\
a_1\lt\cdots\lt a_n\\
b_1\lt\cdots\lt b_n
\end{gather*}
in particular $a\in I_1$ and $b\in I_n$.

Now, we divide the set of indexes in this way:
\begin{gather*}
N = \{j:x\in I_j\cap [a,b] \implies f(x)\lt 0\} \\
P = \{j:x\in I_j\cap [a,b] \implies f(x)\gt 0\}.
\end{gather*}

Take $m\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $b_m = \max\{b_j : j\in N\}$. Then $1\leq m\lt n$ because $b\in I_n$ and $f(b)\gt 0$. Then $m+1\in P$ and so $I_m\cap I_{m+1}=\emptyset$. This implies that the interval $(b_m,a_{m+1})$ is not empty and clearly $$(b_m,a_{m+1})\not\subset\bigcup_{j=1}^n I_j.$$

By the construction the midpoints of $I_m$ and $I_{m+1}$ belong to $[a,b]$ the interval whose endpoints are the midpoints of $I_m$ and $I_{m+1}$ is contained in $[a,b]$ and this interval contains $(b_m,a_{m+1})$,so $(b_m,a_{m+1})\subset [a,b]\subset\bigcup_{j=1}^n I_j$. Contradiction.